# Borders of AdvancedDataGrid disappears in popup

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

The borders of AdvancedDataGrid are disappearing. I am using the same instance of popup object to show at different times.

For the first time the popup and ADG borders are fine but when i launch the popup next time, the borders get disappeared. Though borders reappear if i try to adjust column size. I am not able to get the cause of this issue and therefore not able to rectify it either.

I tried to readjust visibility of ADG and also tried to call invalidateDisplayList(), but no success.

*ADG = AdvancedDataGrid
I am attaching code snippets.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" creationComplete="onCC()" width="1500" height="1000">
 <s:layout>
  <s:VerticalLayout />
 </s:layout>
 <fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
   import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridSortItemRenderer;
   import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
   [Bindable]private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
   
   private function onCC():void
   {
    var obj1:Object = new Object();
    obj1.col1 = "col11";
    obj1.col2 = "col12";
    obj1.col3 = "col13";
    dp.addItem(obj1);
    
    obj1 = new Object()
    obj1.col1 = "col21";
    obj1.col2 = "col22";
    obj1.col3 = "col23";
    dp.addItem(obj1);
   }
   
   var popup:PopupPanel = new PopupPanel();
   private function launchPopup():void
   {
    
    PopUpManager.addPopUp(popup, this as DisplayObject);
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(popup);
   }
  ]]>
 </fx:Script>
 <fx:Declarations>
  <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
  
 </fx:Declarations>
 
 <mx:AdvancedDataGrid sortableColumns="false" sortItemRenderer="{null}" dataProvider="{dp}" draggableColumns="false" >
  <mx:groupedColumns>
   <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="PM1" dataField="col1" />
   <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup headerText="PM2" >
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="NE" dataField="col2" />
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="FE" dataField="col3"/>
   </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>
  </mx:groupedColumns>
 </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
 <mx:Button label="launch popup" click="launchPopup()" />
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="1000" height="750"
      close="titlewindow1_closeHandler(event)">
 <s:layout>
  <s:HorizontalLayout paddingLeft="20" paddingRight="20" paddingTop="20" paddingBottom="20"/>
 </s:layout>
 <fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
   import mx.events.CloseEvent;
   import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
   
   [Bindable] private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
   protected function titlewindow1_closeHandler(event:CloseEvent):void
   {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
   }
   
  ]]>
 </fx:Script>
 <fx:Declarations>
  <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
 </fx:Declarations>
 
 
 <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dg1" sortableColumns="false" sortItemRenderer="{null}" dataProvider="{dp}" draggableColumns="false" width="100%" height="100%">
  <mx:groupedColumns>
   <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="PM1" dataField="col1" />
   <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup headerText="PM2" >
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="NE" dataField="col2" />
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="FE" dataField="col3"/>
   </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>
  </mx:groupedColumns>
 </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
 
 <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dg2" sortableColumns="false" sortItemRenderer="{null}" dataProvider="{dp}" draggableColumns="false" width="100%" height="100%">
  <mx:groupedColumns>
   <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="PM1" dataField="col1" />
   <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup headerText="PM2" >
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="NE" dataField="col2" />
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="FE" dataField="col3"/>
   </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>
  </mx:groupedColumns>
 </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
</s:TitleWindow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a public method that the instance is non-null calls `invalidateList()` of the grid. Example:

```
// Update grids when the display is already instantiated
 public function updates():void{
     its grid.invalidateList();
}
```